# Spring Boot Devtools LiveReload - CSS Injection without browser reload?

Tags: spring-boot, livereload

Currently when there is a css change in a file, the LiveReload server makes the browser reload the whole page. Normal implementations of the LiveReload usually support CSS re-injection without reloading the page.

Does the LiveReload server included in Spring Boot Devtools support CSS injection without making the browser reload the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is currently not supported, as this issue confirms:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9668